# Function srand in C++

Tags: c++, random

This code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
    printf ("First number: %d\n", rand() % 100);
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    printf ("Random number: %d\n", rand() % 100);
    srand ( 1 );
    printf ("Again the first number: %d\n", rand() %100);

    return 0;
}
```

has the following output:

```
First number: 41
Random number: 13
Again the first number: 41
```

There is also the following rule:

> Two different initializations with the same seed, instructs the pseudo-random generator to generate the same succession of results for the subsequent calls to rand in both cases.

I understand the words but I just don't understand the method itself. Why did it return 41 again? Is it random or must it return the same result in every case according to this code?

Comment: This makes debugging easier. If you are running normally use srant(time(NULL)). If there is a bug in your program don't call srand() or call srand(1) and you will get the same sequence of numbers from calls to rand(). Note each call to rand will generate the next number in the sequence but the sequence will always be the same. Note 2: You should just call srand() once in the application.

Comment: @Martin York: Nice point. Never thought about this from debugging point of view. Makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you call `rand()` without first calling `srand()`, the behavior is as if you called `srand()` with `1` as the argument.

This behavior is defined in the original C standard. I don't have a full copy of it handy, but The Open Group's POSIX standards are the next best thing, as they incorporate the full C standard (with some extensions):

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/rand.html

> The srand() function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random numbers to be returned by subsequent calls to rand(). If srand() is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated. If rand() is called before any calls to srand() are made, the same sequence shall be generated as when srand() is first called with a seed value of 1.

The actual result of a `rand()` call for any given seed is implementation-defined, except that for any seed *x*, call *n* to `rand()` after the seeding of the generator must return the same result. So while on your implementation you will always get 41 on the first `rand()` call after calling `srand(1)`, and you will always get the same result (whatever it is) for the second `rand()` call, other implementations may use a different algorithm that produces different results.

Answer (score 7):

The C++ standard defers to the C standard for `rand` and `srand` (see section 26.8 of C++0x):

> The `rand` function has the semantics specified in the C standard, except that the implementation may specify that particular library functions may call `rand`.

The C standard (7.20.2.2 of C99) states quite categorically:

> If `rand` is called before any calls to `srand` have been made, the same sequence shall be generated as when `srand` is first called with a seed value of 1.

So the first time you call `rand`, the seed is 1. It's also 1 the third time you call it which is why you get the same value.

The second time that you called `rand`, the seed had been set based on the current time, which is why you got a different result. It's usually not a good idea to re-seed the random number generator unless you actually *want* the same sequence (such as in testing).

Answer (score 0):

I think this one may be a problem:

If seed is set to 1, the generator is reinitialized to its initial value and produces the same values as before any call to rand or srand.

[srand reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `srand` with a value of `1` resets the generator to its initial state when the program started.

Answer (score 0):

`srand(3)` lets you get repeatable output from the random number generator. This way, you can write programs that depend on random numbers, but test them deterministically. (Typically by having a command-line option to call `srand()` with a supplied argument, so it could be run a hundred times with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... as inputs.)

So this is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because in your initial call to rand the random number generator has not been seeded so it uses a default value of 1 to seed it.