# rand() is generating the same number in guessing game

Tags: c

Programming in C, I am trying to run a game where the computer generates a number between 1 and 100.  However, I keep getting 42 as the number generated... what is wrong with my "rand()"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int guess, tries = 6;
    int number = 1+(rand()%100);

    printf("Pick a number between 1 and 100:");
    scanf_s("%d", &guess);

    while(tries > 0 && guess != number)
    {
        if(guess > number)
            printf("Too high");
        else
            printf("Too low");
        puts(". Guess again:");
        scanf_s("%d",&guess);

        tries--;
    }        

    if(guess == number)
        puts("You win!");
    else
        puts("You lose");
}
```

after a good amount of discussion below I added in the fallowing lines of code

```
#include <time.h>
```

and

```
srand ((unsigned int)time(NULL));
```

but the code failed to run in MS visual studio until i googled the error and it turns out that MSVS needs the variebles to be declared at the top of each function/block.  after doing this the code works fine.  Thank you everyone and sorry for the multiple edits.  corrected code:

```
#include <time.h>
int main (void)
{
int guess, tries = 6, number;
srand ((unsigned int)time(NULL));
number = 1+(rand()%100);
```

The rest is the same. Thank you all.

Comment: How are you seeding your random number generator?

Comment: (Though if you have to come up with a single answer, 42 is a good one.)

Comment: Seed it first with [srand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/).

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297201/function-srand-in-c

Comment: Are you sure it's a bug? [You never can be sure](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/). [Maybe someone had a D42](http://xkcd.com/221/).

Comment: Alternatively, consider to use `arc4random()` (if available on your platform). That does not need to be seeded.

Comment: @user814064 if you keep on modifying your code, none of the answers are going to make any sense

Comment: Voted to close as “unclear what you're asking” since edit 3 dramatically changes the question.

Comment: @P0W: ??? I did not modify any code. I flagged it.

Comment: Maybe the author of your compiler was a fan of the [Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](http://www.amazon.com/Hitchhikers-Guide-Galaxy-Douglas-Adams/dp/0345391802)?

Comment: I don't understand the SO's programmers. Other days this topic could to have -3 downvotes instead of...

Comment: @user814064 sorry it was meant for OP, I didn't notice the userid

Comment: @user2755275 if you keep on modifying your code, none of the answers are going to make any sense

Comment: @P0W I edited the code to include the suggestions of 'user2755275' but i still get the missing ';' before 'type' error

Comment: @PascalCuoq how is it unclear? i generated 42 every time. was asked by another user to edit the code and add in time.h and srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); and I still get errors pertaining to missing ';' before 'type'

Comment: @user2755275 you added `srand ( (unsigned int)time(NULL) );` and there's no question at all, read your title now. Does that even make sense ? If you have other doubt better start on another post, why ruining the existing one. FYI..typos aren't entertained much on SO. and the code works fine, I've already given you a link.

Comment: @P0W Ok, I edited my source back to original. I only edited it in the first place on request by 'ajp15243' ...Anyways I tried to run your version but i get a syntax error.

Comment: @fubrick Well I assumed you would edit the rest of your question to in some way match the code edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
srand ( (unsigned int)time(NULL) );
```

at the beginning of `main`.

Do not forget to Include

```
#include <ctime>
```

or

```
#include <time.h>
```

From the docs:-

> In order to generate random-like numbers, srand is usually initialized
>   to some distinctive value, like those related with the execution time.
>   For example, the value returned by the function time (declared in
>   header ) is different each second, which is distinctive enough for
>   most randoming needs.

Comment: thank you.  it worked after i figured out that MS Visual Studio wants all variables declared at the top of their blocks.  everything works now.

Answer (score 7):

Use a seed with `time`

To seeds the pseudo-random number generator used by `rand()` with the current time.

`srand(time(NULL));`

before calling `rand`

Comment: ok. I added that in and i get a bunch of errors. time undifined, etc.

Comment: @user2755275:- What are the errors??

Comment: Guess, you need to include `time.h`.

Comment: @user2755275 `#include <time.h>`

Comment: ok I cluded math.h but now i have a new error: 'function' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data

Comment: @user2755275 No its [not](http://ideone.com/QsF5P5)

Comment: @user2755275:- You may try this: **srand ( (unsigned int)time(NULL) );** added in my answer too

Comment: ok I tried srand ( (unsigned int)time(NULL) ); and i still get errors. 'number':undeclared identifier and syntax error: missing ';' before 'type'

Comment: @P0W i get the same errors above but i also get 'function': conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data

Comment: @user2755275:- You are missing a **;** (**semicolon**)somewhere. Please check!!!

Comment: @user2755275 Edit your latest source code into your question so we can see exactly what you're compiling to get these errors.

Comment: here is my source code: [link](http://ideone.com/qrn2du)

Answer (score 6):

You need to initialize the random seed with
  `srand (time(NULL));`

In order to do so you also need to include `time.h`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

header file that has the srand(time(NULL)) function in it

```
#include <time.h>
```

.

```
int main (void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
```

seeds the random generator

```
    int guess, tries = 6;
    int number = 1+(rand()%100);

    printf("Pick a number between 1 and 100:");
    scanf_s("%d", &guess);

    while(tries > 0 && guess != number)
    {
        if(guess > number)
            printf("Too high");
        else
            printf("Too low");
        puts(". Guess again:");
        scanf_s("%d",&guess);

        tries--;
    }        

    if(guess == number)
        puts("You win!");
    else
        puts("You lose");
}
```